# Strange C++ console application error

Tags: c++

Code looks like that

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define n 3;
#define m 4;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[n][m];
    bool f=true;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            cin>>arr[i][j];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            if(arr[i][j]!=a[0][j])
                f=false;
    if(f)
            cout<<"Setirler eynidir.";
    else 
        cout<<"muxtelifdir";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Getting bunch of errors

[image]

I can't see any problematic piece of code. Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: Remove the ; at the end of your defines

Comment: `#define` directives don't need the `;` at the end, and if you substitute it literally, you'll find a `;` inside the `[]`, which is an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `#define` is a preprocessor directive, you're making some mistakes in your array delcaration.

```
#define n 3;
#define m 4;

int arr[m][n];

// This translates into 
int arr[3;][4;];
```

You could fix it by removing the `;` after the defines:

```
#define n 3
#define m 4
```

Or even better:

```
static const size_t n = 3;
static const size_t m = 3;
```

As the above will give you type safety elsewhere that you may use `n` or `m`.

Answer (score 8):

`#define`s are not terminated with `;`, so the semicolon is actually pasted there too, yielding

```
int arr[3;][4;];
```

which is invalid code.

Always remember, avoid the preprocessor like the plague.

Comment: @epic: Swap the macros for `unsigned const`s and you'll be fine. Also, why make it global? Oh, and please don't bring the MSVC specific `main` signature. I've edited it out for now, since the error is nothing compiler specific.

Comment: +1 for 'avoid the preprocessor like the plague', but as I commented on  trumpetlicks' answer, 'defines are not terminated with ;' is really wrong formulated: depending on what they define they can end with a semicolon

Comment: @Tom: No, the `#defines` themselves are *never* terminated by anything other than a newline. The content is irrelevant here. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#define
```

statements don't have semi-colons after them.

**[EDIT1]**
Actually they can but, be careful as preprocessor statements like this become strict text replacement.

Comment: You should use a normally-sized font, just like the rest

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Even after the edit, his answer isn't 100% correct, define statements can have semi-colons after them... it just depends on what you are defining

Comment: They don't need semicolons. The issue looks like the OP thought they did. Any semicolon in there is just actually part of the define.

Comment: @TomKnapen that's why i'd give it to the edit, not the answer. The formatting was awful.

Comment: @TomKnapen - Had to take care of the baby, only got partial answer in, formatting was somehow automatic by StackOverflow (putting a # in front of the sentence which was really supposed to be part of the #define statement).  Agree with your comment!

Comment: @Luchian Grigore - Had to take care of the baby, only got partial answer in, formatting was somehow automatic by StackOverflow (putting a # in front of the sentence which was really supposed to be part of the #define statement).

Comment: Just as a personal note, While all are correct and a semicolon can indeed be added as above, it is REALLY REALLY BAD form.  I don't know ANY coder that would actually do this in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon in your `#define`.

define's are expanded by more or less copy+pasting the contents into your source file. Thus

```
int arr[n][m];
```

is expanded into

```
int arr[3;][4;];
```

which is clearly a syntax error. Same goes with your for-loops.